# Adding public facebook feed to UWP

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP project in c#/xaml
I'd like to add the feed of a public facebook page to it, without having to log in, no option to comment or anything, just showing the feed, but I only find how to do it using javascript (for example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin )

Is there a way for me to add the javascript to my UWP project, or is there a different way to do this in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the public facebook feed by the [`/{page-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed) in Graph API.
To use the `/{page-id}/feed`, we should be able to get the access token. We can get it from the app id and app secret in [facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). That you can request the following url to get the facebook feed: `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/feed?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET`.

Then you can use the `GetStringAsync` of [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) to send a GET request to the specified Uri and return the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation.